# Shortcut the code (hide views based on count of number)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, view

what is the best code for below, the code is works well and there is no problem just am finding a better way to write the code, there is 11 views and a count of users so what I need is to hide the views based on users available of 11 lets say we have 11 users and the available only 2 so it will be 2 of 11. the app will hide 1st view and 2nd view but will not hide views from 3 to 11 and so on

```c
    NSInteger countOfViews = 2;
    if (countOfViews == 1) {
        UIView *viewtag1 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:1000];
        UIView *viewtag2 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:2000];
        UIView *viewtag3 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:3000];
        UIView *viewtag4 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:4000];
        UIView *viewtag5 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:5000];
        UIView *viewtag6 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:6000];
        UIView *viewtag7 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:7000];
        UIView *viewtag8 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:8000];
        UIView *viewtag9 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:9000];
        UIView *viewtag10 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:10000];
        UIView *viewtag11 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:11000];

        viewtag1.hidden = YES;
        viewtag2.hidden = NO;
        viewtag3.hidden = NO;
        viewtag4.hidden = NO;
        viewtag5.hidden = NO;
        viewtag6.hidden = NO;
        viewtag7.hidden = NO;
        viewtag8.hidden = NO;
        viewtag9.hidden = NO;
        viewtag10.hidden = NO;
        viewtag11.hidden = NO;
    }


 if (countOfViews == 2) {
        UIView *viewtag1 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:1000];
        UIView *viewtag2 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:2000];
        UIView *viewtag3 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:3000];
        UIView *viewtag4 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:4000];
        UIView *viewtag5 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:5000];
        UIView *viewtag6 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:6000];
        UIView *viewtag7 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:7000];
        UIView *viewtag8 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:8000];
        UIView *viewtag9 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:9000];
        UIView *viewtag10 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:10000];
        UIView *viewtag11 = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:11000];

        viewtag1.hidden = YES;
        viewtag2.hidden = YES;
        viewtag3.hidden = NO;
        viewtag4.hidden = NO;
        viewtag5.hidden = NO;
        viewtag6.hidden = NO;
        viewtag7.hidden = NO;
        viewtag8.hidden = NO;
        viewtag9.hidden = NO;
        viewtag10.hidden = NO;
        viewtag11.hidden = NO;
    }

/*
till if (countOfViews == 11)
*/
```

Comment: You can use [Outlet collection](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/interface-builder-outlet-collections/) which make you create array of outlets, it would be much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSInteger countOfViews = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
            UIView *view = (UIView *)[self.leftScrollView viewWithTag:i * 1000];
            view.hidden = (i <= countOfViews);
    }
```

Comment: Neat & Clean +1

Comment: Clever. Thanks a lot +1